# R CMD check does not respect repository option

Tags: r, package, repository, building

I have the following state in the R console of R-Studio:

```
> options('repos')   
$repos  
[1]   URL of our proxy server
```

But when I run

```
system("R CMD check ./")
```

I get the following error message (translated from German):

```
\* checking package dependencies ... Warning: cannot access index for repository 
https://CRAN.R-project.org/src/contrib
```

The check then fails.
What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checks are run in a separate process running R, so any options settings in RStudio won't be seen.

There are several ways to set the repositories described in the help page `?setRepositories`.  If you want to use the repositories for everything, not just this run, then editing `R_HOME/etc/repositories` is most permanent.  For more flexibility you could do this in one of the startup files by calling `options(repos=...)` there, possibly conditioning on an environment variable or something else.